# Empty image read from file (using file path)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to load an image in two ways:

1. by typing explicitly the file path (in code). i.e.:

   ```
   std::string g = "G:\\Downloads\\L-526.jpg";

   cv::Mat frame = cv::imread(g);
   if (!frame.data)
   {
       printf(" No image data \n ");
   }
   cv::namedWindow("Display window", 1);// Create a window for display.
   cv::imshow("Display window",frame);
   ```
2. by loading the file path from GUI (using "Browse"):

   ```
   std::string f;
   f = LoadImFromGUI();
   //ReplaceStringInPlace(f,"\\","/");  // thought need replacing the double backslash
   cv::waitKey(0);  // NOTE: IN THIS STEP, f IS TOTALLY IDENTICAL to g (from the 1st case)
   cv::Mat frame = cv::imread(f);

   if (!frame.data)
   {
       printf(" No image data \n ");
   }
   cv::namedWindow("Display window", 1);// Create a window for display.
   cv::imshow("Display window", frame);
   ```

In debug mode I get the same path in both 1st and 2nd case. 
But, in the 1st case the image is loaded and displayed, while in the 2nd case (where I browse and load just the same image) I get an empty image.

What should I change in my code?

Comment: I'm wondering why 1st version works since I would assume that it must be cv::Mat frame = cv::imread(g.c_str ());

Comment: And try std::cout << f.c_str () before the imread to check whether your backslash replacement worked!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
g = "G:/Downloads/L-526.jpg";
```